# tomcat log request parameters

Tags: java, logging, tomcat

Is there a way to log request parameters in Tomcat?

If so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tomcat has a `RequestDumperFilter` that can be used to dump the request, including parameters.

Alternatively, if you prefer to change your server config rather than the webapp, there is the `RequestDumperValve`.

Both are described in the [Apache Tomcat Configuration Reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/valve.html).

Answer (score 2):

@mdma is right.  However a word of caution is necessary if your webapp depends on correct handling of UTF-8 query parameters in the URL.

The recommended way for a Tomcat webapp to ensure that UTF-8 characters in URLs are handled correctly in query parameters is to add a filter to the webapp to set the encoding type on the request.  This filter has to do its stuff *before* anything triggers parsing of the parameters.  Unfortunately, Tomcat valves (such as the wonderfully useful `RequestDumperValve`) operate *before* the request hits the webapp's filters.  This causes the query parameters to be parsed assuming Latin-1 encoding ... and the damage is done.

[This page](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding) is a good summary of character coding issues in Tomcat.

Comment: you are right, but it is documented in the link given by mdma: "this Valve is now deprecated in favor of the RequestDumperFilter, which does the same thing in a portable manner. This Filter is included in the examples application: see $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/examples/WEB-INF/classes/filters for the source."